# Dynamically create a function pointer that calls a method on a given instance

Tags: c++, function-pointers, pointer-to-member

I suspect this is impossible, but thought I'd ask. Say I have a class with a method:

```
class A {
public:
    void b(int c);
};
```

I can make a pointer to that member function:

```
void (A::*ptr)(int) = &A::b;
(someAInstance.*ptr)(123);
```

I can also abuse function pointers and make a pointer that takes the `A` argument directly (I don't know if this is safe, but it works on my machine):

```
void (*ptr2)(A*, int) = (void (*)(A*, int))&A::b;
(*ptr2)(&someAInstance, 123);
```

What I *want* is to somehow curry the `A` argument, and create a function pointer that just takes an `int`, but calls the `A::b` method on a particular `A` instance I've predefined. The `A` instance will stay constant for that particular function pointer, but there may be several function pointers all pointing to the same `A::b` method, but using different `A` instances. For example, I could make a separate wrapper function:

```
A* someConstantA = new A;
void wrapper(int c) {
    someConstantA->b(c);
}

void (*ptr3)(int) = &wrapper;
```

Now I can use `ptr3` without knowing which particular `A` it's dispatching the call to, but I had to define a special function to handle it. I need a way to make pointers for any number of `A` instances, so I can't hardcode it like that. Is this in any way possible?

---

**Edit**: Should've mentioned, I'm trapped in C++03 land, and also can't use Boost

Comment: Must it be a function pointer? What you want to do is often done using function objects (e.g. with `std::bind`).

Comment: @KennyTM Anything callable works; I don't know `std::bind`, reading now

Comment: ^^^ or `boost::bind` if you don't have C++11.

Comment: A function object is an object which defines `operator()` so you can use it like a function. Internally it can hold a `this` pointer and a function pointer. `std::bind` is one way to do it or you can hand-roll it.

Comment: @Ben Ah, I just realized `std::bind` is in c++11 too, so I can't use it (edited the environment I'm stuck with into the question). I didn't think of making a class that implements `operator()`; that might be the way to do this

Comment: (template) class that implements operator() is a really easy way to go, IMO. The slightly less legible way would be to typedef void (*ptr2)(A*, int) and use a macro.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have a sufficiently new compiler (e.g. gcc 4.2+), it should include TR1, where you could use `std::tr1::bind`:

```
#include <cstdio>
#include <tr1/functional>

class A {
public:
    void b(int c) {
        printf("%p, %d\n", (void*)this, c);
    }
};

int main() {
    A* a = new A;

    std::tr1::function<void(int)> f =
        std::tr1::bind(&A::b, a, std::tr1::placeholders::_1);  // <--
    f(4);

    delete a;

    return 0;
}
```

It is also doable in pure C++03 without TR1, but also much more messier:

```
std::binder1st<std::mem_fun1_t<void, A, int> > f =
    std::bind1st(std::mem_fun(&A::b), a);
```

You could also write your own function objects.

Note that, in all the above cases, you need to be very careful about the lifetime of `a` since that is a bare pointer. With `std::tr1::bind`, you could at least wrap the pointer in a `std::tr1::shared_ptr`, so that it can live just as long as the function object.

```
std::tr1::shared_ptr<A> a (new A);
std::tr1::function<void(int)> f =
    std::tr1::bind(&A::b, a, std::tr1::placeholders::_1);
```

Answer (score 3):

Don't create a wrapper *function*, create a wrapper *[functor](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Function_object#In_C_and_C.2B.2B)*. This allows you to encapsulate whatever state you want to (e.g. an `A*`) in a callable object.

```
class A {
public:
    void b(int c) {}
};

struct wrapper {
  A* pA;
  void (A::*pF)(int);
  void operator()(int c) { (pA->*pF)(c); }
  wrapper(A* pA, void(A::*pF)(int)) : pA(pA), pF(pF) {}
};

int main () {
  A a1;
  A a2;

  wrapper w1(&a1, &A::b);
  wrapper w2(&a2, &A::b);

  w1(3);
  w2(7);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

If you are using C++11, you might use a lambda (untested code):

```
template<typename T, typename A>
 std::function<void(A)> curry(T& object, void (T::*ptr)(A))
{
  return [](A a) { (object.*ptr)(std::forward<A>(a)); }
}
```

Comment: I would kill for a lambda, but sadly no; stuck with 03

Answer (score 0):

I'd be using [Boost::bind](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_49_0/libs/bind/bind.html) for this.

Basically:

```
class A
{
    int myMethod(int x)
    {
        return x*x;
    }
};

int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
    A test();
    auto callable = boost::bind(&A::myMethod, &A, _1);

    // These two lines are equivalent:
    cout << "object with 5 is: " << test.myMethod(5) << endl;
    cout << "callable with 5 is: " << callable(5) << endl;
    return 0;
}
```

I think that should work.  I'm also using auto in here to deduce the type returned by boost::bind() at compile-time, which your compiler may or may not support.  See this [other question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6412065/what-is-the-return-type-of-boostbind) at stackoverflow for an explanation of the return type of bind.

Boost supports back to Visual Studio 2003 (I think) and this all this will work there, though you'll be using BOOST_AUTO I think.  See the other question already linked for an explanation.

Answer (score 0):

What you want to do is not possible.
To see why, assume that it is possible - the function pointer must point to a function somewhere in your executable or one of its libraries, so it must point to a function that knows which instance of `A` to call, much like your wrapper function. Because the instance of `A` is not known until runtime, you'd have to create those functions at runtime, which isn't possible.

What you're trying to do is possible in C++03, as long as you're happy to pass around a function object rather than a function pointer.

As others have already given solutions with C++11 lambdas, TR1 and boost (all of which are prettier than the below), but you mentioned you can't use C++11, I'll contribute one in pure C++03:

```
int main()
{
    void (A::*ptr)(int) = &A::b;
    A someAInstance;

    std::binder1st<std::mem_fun1_t<void,A,int> > fnObj =
         std::bind1st(std::mem_fun(ptr), &someAInstance);
    fnObj(321);
};
```

Comment: I think [KennyTM's answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/9983036/309308) already covers the same C++03 implementation, but thanks for the explanation at the beginning

Comment: @MichaelMrozek So it does.. he's updated it since I first read the existing answers

Answer (score 0):

I've worked something out with a template Delegate class.

```
// T is class, R is type of return value, P is type of function parameter
template <class T, class R, class P> class Delegate
{
    typedef R (T::*DelegateFn)(P);
private:
    DelegateFn func;
public:
    Delegate(DelegateFn func)
    {
        this->func = func;
    }
    R Invoke(T * object, P v)
    {
        return ((object)->*(func))(v);
    }
};

class A {
private:
    int factor;
public:
    A(int f) { factor = f; }
    int B(int v) { return v * factor; }
};

int _tmain(int argc, _TCHAR* argv[])
{
    A * a1 = new A(2);
    A * a2 = new A(3);

    Delegate<A, int, int> mydelegate(&A::B);

    // Invoke a1->B
    printf("Result: %d\n", mydelegate.Invoke(a1, 555));

    // Invoke a2->B
    printf("Result: %d\n", mydelegate.Invoke(a2, 555));

    _getch();
    delete a1;
    delete a2;
    return 0;
}
```