# Delayed Function Call in a Delayed Function Call

Tags: c++, function-pointers, delayed-execution, stdbind

Basically what I want to do is this:

```
std::function< int( void ) > foo = &getInt;
int magicNumber = 13;
std::function< int( void ) > delayedAdd = std::bind( std::plus, magicNumber, getInt );
```

Clearly this won't work. I need to somehow wrap the `getInt` *call* so that it happens right before the `std::plus` function happens. Then all that would need to be delayed till I call `delayedAdd`.

I'm working with Qt5.0 outside a QObject so I can't `connect` a lambda to a `SLOT`. But I want to `connect` something like the `delayedAdd` to the `SLOT` instead.

+tag funception

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can defer the function call by using `std::bind`:

```
using namespace std;

int getInt() {
    cout << "getInt!" << endl;
    return 42;
}

function<int(void)> foo = &getInt;
int magicNumber = 13;

cout << "before delayed definition" << endl;
function<int(void)> delayed = std::bind(plus<int>(), magicNumber, bind(foo));
cout << "after delayed definition" << endl;

int i = delayed();

cout << "after delayed call" << endl;
```

Output:

> before delayed definition
>   after delayed definition
>   getInt!
>   after delayed call

You do not need to define `foo` like you did, either. You can just bind `getInt` directly in the definition of `delayed`:

```
function<int(void)> delayed = bind(plus<int>(), magicNumber, bind(getInt));
```

For more details on std::bind, check [N3797](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2013/n3797.pdf), paragraph 20.9.9.
For a more concrete explanation, [cppreference](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/functional/bind) says:

> **std::bind return type**
>   ...
>   Member function operator()
>   Given an object g obtained from an earlier call to bind, when it is invoked in a function call expression g(u1, u2, ... uM), an invocation of the stored object of type std::decay::type takes place, with arguments defined as follows:
>   ...
>   - If std::is_bind_expression::value == true (i.e. another bind subexpression was used as an argument in the initial call to bind), then that bind subexpression is invoked immediately and its result is passed to the invocable object. If the bind subexpression has any placeholder arguments, they are picked from u1, u2, ....
>   ...

Comment: Gadzooks! What just happened? What type is bind returning to plus? I thought that bind returned a function object!

Comment: There are some things, you just don't want to know ;)

Comment: More seriously, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6412065/what-is-the-return-type-of-boostbind touches this question, but does not provide a lot of details

Comment: So am I understanding correctly that the outer bind is doing the conversion here, so the plus function only ever sees the two ints?