# Boost bind return type difference

Tags: c++, boost, bind

I have looked through the discussion on [What is the return type of boost::bind?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6412065/what-is-the-return-type-of-boostbind) and see the short answer is that you don't need to know.

While I have a function that taking "bind(...) result" as an argument and I find following difference behaviour

Working case 1

```
   void func(int a){};
   myfunc(bind(&obj::func,this,_1));
```

Not working case 2 ( when I want to bind the func2 with 2 argument)

```
   void func2(int a, int b){};
   myfunc(bind(&obj::func2,this,_1,_2));
```

Made it working with case 3

```
   void func3(int a, int b){};
   myfunc(bind(&obj::func3,this,_1, 10));
```

So my question is what's the differnt on retrun type of following 3?

```
bind(&obj::func,this,_1));
bind(&obj::func2,this,_1,10)); //why this one can be passed the same type as above one?
bind(&obj::func3,this,_1,_2));
```

As `myfunc` is a quite embedded in template and overloading functions, I didn't yet find how it is defined to take "bind(...)" as an argument. That's why I didn't attach the code for `myfunc`

Comment: So your real question is what type should the argument of `myfunc` be?

Comment: @SingerOfTheFall , by understanding the return type of bind, I can self design the wanted argument type of myfuc I think

Comment: What's the error you get?

Comment: Do you understand what `std::bind()` actually *does*?

Comment: "the short answer is that you don't need to know."...

Answer (score 0):

As the answer you linked says, you don't actually need to know the exact return type. That type, however, is compatible with `boost::function`, so you can do this (as a simplest example with `void(void)`):

```
typedef boost::function<void(void)> myFunctionType;

// this is the function that you want to bind
void foo(){}
// this is the function that should take it as an argument
void myOtherFunction(myFunctionType f);
<...>
// this is how you bind it
myFunctionType bar = boost::bind(foo);
// and this is how you pass it as argument
myOtherFunction(bar);
```